# Bug when double backing to jobs

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Was filtering for a job using "C#".  Clicked a result...read a little about it.  Clicked the "company" this job belonged too.  Read a little.  Pressed the back key twice to go back to the job filters.  Get an error or missing page link.

Steps to reproduce.

1. Use the cog wheel to apply a filter to the "search jobs".  Use the filter "C#" for instance for tech you like
2. Click a job result
3. Midway through you can click a big blue shiny button that allows you to learn more about the company - Click to read about the company
4. Click to go back
5. Click to go back again (To return to the search jobs - where you cog wheeled "C#")

Result:
[image]

**Funny thing is this works fine if you filter for tech you dislike.  For tech you like this breaks.**  Here's a screencast of it: https://www.screencast.com/t/1DfmzxXwi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this! The issue was when the tags that were being searched had uppercases (so should you select the tag from the tag editor, it would be lowercased and then it would work as expected).

This is now fixed, but as there's a 301 redirection there, you may need to clear your cache for your browser to get the new destination.

I promise we have reasons to do so! here are some details of what we are doing and why:

- As part of our SEO strategy, we launched "landing pages". Those are pages like [developer-jobs-using-c#](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/developer-jobs-using-c%23) that are nothing else than a filter.
- We already had things like [/jobs?tl=c#](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?tl=c%23) indexed by the search engines.
- In order for the search engines to "pass the juice" to the new url, we added a 301 redirection to the landing page when they visited the old url.
- Then we noticed that external sites were linking to `/jobs?tl=some-weird-stuff-that-doesnt-make-sense` and we were redirecting the crawlers to `/jobs/developer-jobs-using-some-weird-stuff-that-doesnt-make-sense`... and for some reason, we were getting lots of clicks there! (that page obviously had 0 jobs each and every time).
- What we did at this point, is verify that the tag is valid... and in the case of an invalid tag, return a 404. That eventually gets the wrong landing page deindexed from the search engines.

That all works great... but... `developer-jobs-using-C#` has the tag `C#`... which isn't valid (the valid one is [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), in lowercase).

What I did, is just do a lowercase of the destination url when somebody visits an old link. `/jobs?tl=C#` now redirects to `developer-jobs-using-c#` and then it all works.

Comment: That is one strange bug...but if you got it great.